# Set apache subdomain reverse proxy for bitbucket

Tags: apache, subdomain, bitbucket, reverse-proxy

I read several documentations "how to make it possible" like these

*confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html*

*httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html*

I not even try to use https for the moment. First I wanna a small success, access bitbucket via my subdomain...

Running:

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Bitbucket 5.0.0

Apache/2.4.18

/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/bitbucket.properties:

```
server.port=7990
server.secure=false
server.scheme=http
server.proxy-port=80
server.redirect-port=80
server.proxy-name=mysub.mydomain.mytld
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysub.mydomain.mytld

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off


          ProxyPass "/" "http://mydomain.mytld:7990/"
          ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://mydomain.mytld:7990/"

</VirtualHost>
```

bitbucket base url (bitbucket settings administration)

```
 http://mysub.mydomain.mytld
```

restart commands

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

within /opt/atlassian/bitbucket/5.0.0/bin/
./stop-bitbucket.sh
./start-bitbucket.sh
```

- With the default bitbucket.properties bitbucket works, when I call http://mydomain:mytld:7990/
- With my custom bitbucket.properties, when I call http://mysub.mydomain.mytld/ shows 500 internal error. In the apache logs:

  "No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule."

Comment: FYI, if your connector on port 7990 is receiving traffic from a reverse proxy, then you shouldn't have `server.redirect-port=80` defined. redirect-port is commonly used when you have two connectors, and want to redirect traffic from one to another (e.g. from HTTP to HTTPS). In this case, your reverse proxy is sending traffic to your connector on port 7990 and so it shouldn't be redirecting anywhere. Having said that in your example redirect-port will be inactive because it goes hand in hand with other configuration - I'd simply suggest removing it for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was wrong virtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.tld:80> 

ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:7990/"

ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:7990/"
```

localhost... instead the public domain